# vbscript dropdown in function without using HTML (classic ASP)

Tags: html, vbscript, asp-classic, dropdown

I am working on a classic asp page with a pre-existing vbscript function that forms a document.

Is there a way to make a dropdown within vbscript itself that doesn't depend on HTML?

I have an xml object with what is needed to load the dropdown but I need to load the actual dropdown.

Luckily, it just needs to print on the form, there is no save to a database.

There isn't much code to post except that it would go in a function such as:

```
Function getDropdownA(ByVal strInput)
     ' put dropdown here, loading into it the strInput
End
```

Comment: Is there a way to make a dropdown within vbscript itself that doesn't depend on HTML? the short answer is **no**

Comment: In order to appear on the web page it would have to be constructed with HTML. What do you mean by "doesn't depend on" HTML?

Comment: I may be asking for the impossible....

Comment: @Rafael , please promote your comment to an answer, and I will accept it.  Of course, that is an answer also..... Thanks

Comment: @DonZacharias -- the way the page is structured, an entire re-write would have to be done if HTML were used,  so we changed it to an edit box in our case... however the answer here appears to be "no" and that's ok, sometimes, that is what the answer is!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well , relative to your question.

> Is there a way to make a dropdown within vbscript itself that doesn't
>   depend on HTML?

A short answer is **no**.

Ok, Why not? because `classic-asp` like almost every other preprocessor languages for web applications, doesn't have the faculty to interact directly with your browser. instead the language provides you a set of methods to write and recieve data from the user-agent (not necesarry a browser).

and the browser relies on `HTML`,`XHTML`,`CSS` and derivatives to construct an interface to the user, and due to fact that preprocessor doesn't interact directly with `HTML`, that its the reason because you can't make a dropdown in pure vbscript bypassing `HTML` code.

i hope this answer provides a clear view about the scope of `classic-asp` and the related technologies