# asp, server-side populate textbox

Tags: asp-classic, server-side

Questions about this do exist on stack but the answers are either wrong or of little use.

Coming from older VB, and being familiar with Java (where the code runs fine on client), trying to populate a textbox server side asp is driving me up the wall.  Microsoft's logic is simply inane (regardless of topic).

Yes, it's probably due to a lack of conceptualization on my part, but if the textbox has an id and I can pull data, why can't I write to a different textbox with a named id?

I can write to the body, so why not a text box with a named id?  It makes no sense to me.  Is there some issue with just text boxes?

Any feedback, esp with a tech explanation of what I fail to understand, would be greatly appreciated.

Very simple code example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><body>
  <form action="p3.asp" method="post">
    AnyVal: <input type="text" name="AnyVal" size="20" />
    Other: <input type="text" name="Other" size="20" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>

<%
  dim sRet
  sRet=Request.Form("AnyVal")

  If sRet <> "" Then
    Response.Write("Your Val is: " & sret &  "!<br>")
    Other.value=sRet
  End If
%>

</body></html>
```

Answer (score 2):

> Yes, it's probably due to a lack of conceptualization on my part,

I agree with that statement, you simply can't do that ... let me explain it simple taking an extract of recent answer i wrote in the past days

[vbscript dropdown in function without using HTML (classic ASP)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35040800/961234)

> classic-asp like almost every other preprocessor languages for web
>   applications, doesn't have the faculty to interact directly with your
>   browser. instead the language provides you a set of methods to write
>   and recieve data from the user-agent (not necesarry a browser).
>
> and the browser relies on HTML,XHTML,CSS and derivatives to construct
>   an interface to the user, and due to fact that preprocessor doesn't
>   interact directly with HTML, that its the reason because you can't
>   make a dropdown in pure vbscript bypassing HTML code.

What are you trying to do is to treat your form elements as objects using ASP language, unfortunately you can't do that because the form elements are not visible to server preprocessor (ASP).

You need to write code to actually on the HTML, because such form elements doesn't exists to the ASP engine

```
<%
  dim sRet
  sRet=Request.Form("AnyVal")

  If sRet <> "" Then
    Response.Write("Your Val is: " & sret &  "!<br>")
  End If
%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><body>
  <form action="p3.asp" method="post">
    AnyVal: <input type="text" value="<%=sRet%>" name="AnyVal" size="20" />
    Other: <input type="text" value"<%=sRet%>" name="Other" size="20" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>

</body></html>
```

I hope I'm being clear in my explanation about how really ASP works

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code I think the easiest way to achieve what you want is the following.

```
<%
  dim sRet
  sRet=Request.Form("AnyVal")
%>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><body>
  <form action="p3.asp" method="post">
    AnyVal: <input type="text" name="AnyVal" size="20" />
    Other: <input type="text" name="Other" size="20" value="<%= Sret %>" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

 <%
  If sRet <> "" Then
    Response.Write("Your Val is: " & sret &  "!<br>")

  End If
%>
  </form> 


</body></html>
```

Your Classic ASP is server side code and your form elements are client side, so they can't interact with each other.

NB You've tagged this as Classic ASP.  If you mean ASP.net then you need to use a server side control - `<asp:Textbox>`  Note that VB and VBScript are different, just as Java and JavaScript are different

Edit - @Rafael beat me to posting this, and he gives a more detailed explanation of more or less the same, so you should probably accept his answer

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for your kind replies, but I think I got it nailed.

I'll post the code below, in case others may find it useful.

I kinda knew that asp & java interact with html differently, but one of the things that threw me was using a javascript variable to get the server side variable.

for example, 
  var cret;
  cret = <%= sret %>

which works if is sret is a number but not if it's a string (don't know why, perhaps someone could enlighten me).

I did figure out getting asp to generate a text box on the fly and populate it.

But, I really wanted the javasript on the client side to do this part.  From a practical point of view, I could have just given up and let asp do it, but I became a bit ocb about the whole thing.

I've read a lot of postings, blogs, etc. about this issue.  It seemed to me that the proposed solutions were either convoluted of just didn't work.  The question seems to get asked a lot, so I was surprised to find no fairly straightforward answer.

Everything I wanted to do could have been done in javascript, even using runat=server.  But I specifically wanted to keep some of the code behind the page private.  afaik, this needed asp.

I suspect that this is the main reason other want to populate elements via javascript whicle still using asp on the server.

The following code uses a form post, where asp can do some manipulation and  generate an input element which can be subseqently accessed/manipulated by javascript.  For this example the input element is hidden.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<title>asp java test</title>
</head>
<body>

  <form action="p5.asp" method="post">
    <p>Paste into the yellow box and then click Go.</p>
    Set Val: 
    <input type="text" id="setval" name="setval" size="30"
     style="background-color: #FFFFCC" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" /><p>

    Ret Val: 
    <input type="text" id="retval" name="retval" size="30" />
  </form>


  <!-- Server Side -->
  <%
    dim sret
    sret = Request.Form("setval")

    If sret = "" Then sret = " Nada"

//  <!-- gen output server side-->
    response.write("<input type='hidden' id='hid1' name='hid1' value='" & sret & "'/><br>")

  %>

  <!-- Client Side -->

  <script language = "JavaScript">
    var cret;

    {

//    Get the val
      cret = document.getElementById("hid1").value;

//    Populate the output box
      document.getElementById("retval").value = cret;
    }

  </script>

</body></html>
```

Seems to work quite well for it's intended purpose.

Gary

Comment: ok, only a note to your solution: you are misundertanding how really works the ASP (jScript/VbScript) **Server -side** and The **client side** that is HTML, CSS and Javascript ... Javascript in the client is no the same that Jscript on the server. I suggest reading further about the topic.

Comment: for your javacript proble you can do this     var cret; cret='<%= sret %>';

Comment: Hi Rafael,

'Reading further' is valid, and I will be doing that.   I think the biggest issue I face is needing to 'un-learn' concepts before being able to fully grasp new ones. 

Case in point: I was about to say that  I already tried using:  cret='<%= sret %>';   --  and it don't work for strings.  

Then I noticed the chr(39) wrapping the call.  Wow!  That simple. 

Thank you.

As you probly know, in vb, we wrap strings in extra chr(38) quotes, esp if sending to a SQL data soucre.  Now I understand a little bit more.

:-)